# Define Local Variable in Common Lisp loop

Tags: loops, variables, common-lisp

I would like to know if there is a way to introduce some local variable in a Common Lisp `loop` construct, without any kind of auto increment on it - just as, say, a shortcut syntax to avoid using let outside of the loop.

Comment: WITH is the LOOP clause you are looking for: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/06_abb.htm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We'll start wit the simples one. If you let loop do something with any of the accumulation words you can just name a binding and it gets created. Here I make the two bindings `odds` and `evens` since I want both values returned and counting is one of the verbs described in [Loop for black belts](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html) and of course [CLHS loop specification](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/m_loop.htm):

```scm
(loop :for num :in '(1 3 5 6 3 3)
      :counting (oddp num) :into odds
      :counting (evenp num) :into evens
      :finally (return (values odds evens)))
; ==> 5 
; ==> 1
```

Also described in the documentation the more general way would be to use `with` clause:

```scm
(loop :with odds := 0 :and evens := 0
      :for num in '(1 3 5 6 3 3)
      :if (oddp num) :do (incf odds)
      :else :do (incf evens)
      :finally (return (values odds evens)))
; ==> 5 
; ==> 1
```

You already know of `for e = value then new-value` since it steps, but I add it here for completion. Note that the order is important:

```scm
(loop :for odds := 0 :then (if (oddp num) (1+ odds) odds)
      :for evens := 0 :then (if (evenp num) (1+ evens) evens)
      :for num :in '(1 3 5 6 3 3)
      :finally (return (values odds evens)))
; ==> 5 
; ==> 1
```

As a last example we have `&aux` elements in functions. It creates `let*` bindings without `let*` and indent. It is often a real alternative:

```scm
(defun count-odds (list &aux (odds 0) (evens 0))
  (loop :for num in list
        :if (oddp num) :do (incf odds)
        :else :do (incf evens))
  (values odds evens))
```

Note tat we don't need to use `finally` since the altered bindings are available outside of `loop`

Knowing CL it's probably a couple more I have missed, but these are the ones I use.